# unable to chdir or not a git archive

Tags: git

I'm trying to setup my first git server and I'm having problems cloning to my local machine.

On the server I have done the following

```
cd /var/www/html/
mkdir my-first-repo
cd my-first-repo
touch file1.txt
git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /var/www/html/my-first-repo/.git/
```

Then on my local machine if I enter the following

```
git clone root@myserver:my-first-repo/.git
```

I get the following error messages

```
fatal: 'my-first-repo/.git': unable to chdir or not a git archive
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

root has ssh access so I was expecting it to work fine.

Any suggestions on how to fix this would be great?

Thanks

Comment: Say `git clone root@myserver:my-first-repo` -- but I think you're only allowed to clone from *bare* repositories.

Comment: If I remove the /.git part I still get the same error messages

Comment: Yeah... I think you can only clone a bare repo. Make a bare repo, *push* your original repo into that, and then *pull* from the bare repo.

Comment: @Kerrek you are VERY wrong, ALL repos can be cloned.

Comment: @Migol: Oh, OK, never mind then -- sorry! (But you cannot *push* into every repo, right?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't add `.git` i.e. do it like this:

```
git clone root@myserver:my-first-repo
```

**EDIT:** Wait... you created repo on HTTP server and try to access it via SSH. This is bad idea, but this should work then:

```
git clone root@myserver:/var/www/html/my-first-repo
```

The `myserver:my-first-repo` directs you to `$HOME/my-first-repo`.

Comment: If I remove the /.git part I still get the same error messages

Comment: Thanks @Migol your edit has worked.

This isn't the permanent solution, I'm just going through a book and this method was first so I wanted to make sure it was working before I move onto the next part using Gitosis.

Does that sound like a better option?

Comment: Gitosis looks like best option :) But for the love of God, don't do it on root user!!

Comment: No no no, I won't. I was only using root here as I knew it would have access.

Thanks for the quick help